# Array of functions and Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

Tags: arrays, function, fortran, dimension, geany

I am trying to set my function `f` as an array, but I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

#0  0x6f8b36e3
#1  0x6f8a2722
#2  0x402752
#3  0x747bd411
```

I have to solve the Kepler's equation:`f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M` for each value of `M`.So, if I have an array `M` of dimension 8, my program will calculate  8   zeros. The thing is that, if I write `f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(1)` I will calculate the first zero,and if  I write `f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(8)` I will calculate the last zero.But ,my problem is that if I want to calculate all zeros at once, I would have to write `f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(1:8)` and my program should type all zeros, but,that doesnt happen and i get the error i mentioned earlier.Here is the code:

SUBROUTINE (I USED EXTERNALLY):This subroutine is the bisection method (to get zeros):

```
   subroutine bisecc(f,xl,xr,kmax,tol,k,xm)
  implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
  real*8 f
  fl=f(xl)
  fr=f(xr)

  if(fl*fr .gt. 0.0D0) goto 100  
  do k=1,kmax
    xm=(xr+xl)/2.0D0              
    fm=f(xm)

    dif=abs((xr-xl)/xm)        
    if(dif .lt. tol) goto 200    
    write(*,*) k,xm!,dif  
    if (fm*fr .le. 0.0D0) then
      xl=xm
      fl=fm
    else
      xr=xm
      fr=fm
    end if
  end do

  return
200   write(*,*) 'WISHED PRECISION  REACHED'
      return
100   write(*,*) 'BAD CHOICE OF DATA'
      return
      end
```

MAIN PROGRAM:

```
       include 'bisecc.f' 
   implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)            
   external f     
   real*8 f    
   ! I  WRITE  THE INTERVAL OF MY 8 ZEROS(left and right point)
   b=0.1D0


   xl1=-0.5D0                
   xr1=0.D0                 
   xl2=xr1+b
   xr2=1.D0
   xl3=xr2+b
   xr3=2.D0
   xl4=xr3+b
   xr4=3.D0
   xl5=xr4+b
   xr5=4.D0
   xl6=xr5+b
   xr6=5.D0
   xl7=xr6+b
   xr7=6.D0
   xl8=xr7+b
   xr8=7.D0        
   kmax=100                            
   tol=0.0001D0                               
   call bisecc(f,xl1,xr1,kmax,tol,k,xm1)         
   call bisecc(f,xl2,xr2,kmax,tol,k,xm2)          
   call bisecc(f,xl3,xr3,kmax,tol,k,xm3)         
   call bisecc(f,xl4,xr4,kmax,tol,k,xm4)         
   call bisecc(f,xl5,xr5,kmax,tol,k,xm5)         
   call bisecc(f,xl6,xr6,kmax,tol,k,xm6)         
   call bisecc(f,xl7,xr7,kmax,tol,k,xm7)          
   call bisecc(f,xl8,xr8,kmax,tol,k,xm8)                     
   write(*,*) 'Program ended'
   stop
   end program
```

---

```
   real*8 function f(psi)
   implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
   real*8 M(8)
   dimension f(8)
      e=0.2056D0                          
      pi=acos(-1.0D0)                        
      M=(/pi/4.D0,pi/2.D0,3.D0/4.D0*pi,pi,5.D0/4.D0*pi,3.D0*
 &    pi/2.D0,7.D0/4.D0*pi,2.D0*pi/)
      c=sqrt((1.0D0-e)/(1.0D0+e))                
   f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(1:8)             !KEPLER EQUATION

   return
   end function
```

EXAMPLE:
Here I wanted to calculate the value of psi for the first value of M, `M(1)=pi/4`.

In https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxEv2.jpg you can see that `psi=0.95303344726562489`. So I have just calculated the first zero. But, you can also see this message 7 times `datos mal elegidos`. It means that the program can only show me that zero (for `M(1)`), and the other 7 zeros are not calculated, *because I wrote* `f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(1)`.
What should I write so I can get the result of *all* zeros instead of 1, like in this example?

Comment: You will have to show the code that does the  writing. And please compile your code with `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall` or equivalent and try again and report the output.

Comment: i dont get compilation errors or build errors,the error i get it when i execute the program and it shows in a cmd.

Comment: If you want to check the code ,you can give me your email adress and ill send you both files .f so you run it in your own pc,only if you want

Comment: I submitted a new question and if you know the answer,it could be a great alternative to solve this question:"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460615/fortran-function-do-loop-only-prints-last-value"

Comment: It is possible to change f() to be a function returning an array, but if it is used in bisection, isn't it better to keep it just a scalar function and call the bisection routine for each element of input array(s)...?

Comment: I mean to copy and paste the error message you get when you run the code after new compiling.

Comment: Screenshot:http://imgur.com/RyOBnTU               And this one is a proof that i dont get compilation errors:http://imgur.com/hXM8SVn

Comment: Please always prefer copying and pasting the text instead of a screenshot. It is because possibility to search. Text can be searched, screenshots can't be.

Comment: And please follow my previous advice and compile the code with `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall name_of_your_file` in the directory containing the file. Then run the resulting `a.exe` and copy the output here. As text, copy and paste it here **as text**, do not post any more screenshots.

Comment: And if you really have to use a screenshot for some reason, do not use imgur, use the StackOverflow image paste.

Comment: @roygvib The function is not in a module. But worse, an array valued function would not be compatible with the bisection routine.

Comment: @VladimirF Though it looks like a duplicate, I put some code anyway (hoping some use). And yes, there are too many "8" there XD

Comment: It is so specific that I don't think it is a duplicate. Or a link would not be useful to the OP.

Comment: @stepdead0X Are you studying at an English speaking university? Don't get me wrong but for many courses, reports, essays, theses it will be worth learning the you put space after a comma and a full stop, not before. And that I is spelled capital and that you use an apostrophe in I'll or isn't. Otherwise your teachers might not be happy.

Comment: im spanish,so you can imagine what this  means when we talk about english language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function `f()` is used in the bisection routine `bisecc()`, I think it would be much simpler to pass each input to `bisecc()` via a DO loop, rather than making `f()` a function returning an array (because the latter requires to modify `bisecc()` also). We can pass the value of `M` to `f()` in various ways (which is almost FAQ and I believe there are a lot of Q/A pages). One simple way is to contain `f()` in the main program and use host association for `M`. So a simplified code may look like

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer  kmax, kiter, i
    real*8   xl( 8 ), xr( 8 ), xans( 8 ), tol, M( 8 ), b, pi

    pi   = acos(-1.0D0)                 
    kmax = 100
    tol  = 1.0d-8

    M = [ pi/4.D0,      pi/2.D0,      3.D0/4.D0*pi, pi, &
          5.D0/4.D0*pi, 3.D0*pi/2.D0, 7.D0/4.D0*pi, 2.D0*pi ]
    ! or M = [( i, i=1,8 )] * pi/4.0D0

    ! Use a fixed interval for simplicity.
    xl   =  0.0d0
    xr   = 10.0d0
    xans =  0.0d0

    do i = 1, 8
        call bisecc( f, xl( i ), xr( i ), kmax, tol, kiter, xans( i ) )
        ! print *, "check: f(xans(i)) = ", f( xans( i ) )
    enddo

contains

function f( psi ) result( res )
    implicit none
    real*8  psi, e, res
    e = 0.2056D0
    res = psi - e * sin( psi ) - M( i )   !<-- this "M(i)" refers to that defined above
end function 

end program
```

with an external `bisecc` routine (a little modified so as not to use GOTO)

```
subroutine bisecc( f, xl, xr, kmax, tol, k, xm )
    implicit none
    real*8  f, xl, xr, tol, xm
    external f
    integer kmax, k
    real*8  fl, fr, fm, dif

    fl = f( xl )
    fr = f( xr )
    if( fl * fr > 0.0D0 ) then
        write(*,*) "bad input data (xl,xr)"
        return
    endif

    do k = 1, kmax
        xm = (xr + xl) / 2.0D0              
        fm = f( xm )

        dif = abs( (xr-xl) / xm )
        if ( dif < tol ) then
            write(*,*) "bisection converged: k=", k, "xm=", xm
            return
        endif

        if ( fm * fr <= 0.0D0 ) then
            xl = xm
            fl = fm
        else
            xr = xm
            fr = fm
        end if
    end do  !! iteration

    write(*,*) "bisection did not converge: k=", k, "xm=", xm
end
```

which gives

```
 bisection converged: k=          31 xm=  0.95299366395920515     
 bisection converged: k=          31 xm=   1.7722388869151473     
 bisection converged: k=          30 xm=   2.4821592587977648     
 bisection converged: k=          30 xm=   3.1415926571935415     
 bisection converged: k=          29 xm=   3.8010260276496410     
 bisection converged: k=          29 xm=   4.5109464414417744     
 bisection converged: k=          29 xm=   5.3301916457712650     
 bisection converged: k=          29 xm=   6.2831853143870831
```

The answer seems to agree with the plot of the [Kepler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) with e = 0.2056 (so `bisecc()` is probably OK).

[image: kepler.png]

The above code still has a lot of points for improvement. In particular, it is usually more convenient to include a function like `f()` into a module (or even include all routines into a module). We can also pass `M` by making it a module variable and `use` it from `f()` (rather than using `common` statements) or via host association, so please try it if interested.

Comment: (The above "answer" is in fact a workaround because it does not answer why segmentation fault occurs in the OP's code, or how to return an array from a function.)

Comment: Thank you for the help,i know that you guys are a bit rigorous with the code,because this may be useful for anyone,but the way i code this,is the way our teacher taught us,so at the moment i have to work like him and use what he showed us,in the future  ill learn to code the proper way,my physics teacher says that he isnt a programmer he is a physicist that just uses a pc to solve problems,so we are not very rigorous with the code

Comment: @stepdead0X No problem, "common" is a bit old but still effective way to pass variables. When the number of variables become large, it may be useful to think of switching common to a module at that time (to avoid various pitfalls of common). This SO Docs may be a nice place to start http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/topics

Comment: we began the subject of computational physics a month ago,still need a lot more stuff to learn like modules and so on.

Answer (score 1):

MY SOLUTION:I will add a more generic solution to my exercise,avoiding the mentioned error.This is a more generic solution,for N values of M,instead of 8:

```
   include 'bisecc.f'  
   implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)             
   external f     
   parameter (Mlong=100)              !Number of elemnts of M(from 0 to 2pi)
   real*8 f ,M                               
   common M,e                         !to not copy them twice 

   kmax=100                           !max number of iterations
   tol=0.0001D0                       !Tolerance of 0.01%
   e=0.2056D0                         !Mercury excentricity
   pi=acos(-1.0D0)                     
   c=sqrt((1.0D0-e)/(1.0D0+e))     

   open(10,file='153b.dat',status='unknown') !data will apear in a .dat file
   write(*,*)'            i        M                 Theta(rad)'
   write(10,*)'           i        M                 Theta(rad)'

  do i=1,Mlong
     xl=-1.D0                     !LEFT STARTING POINT
     xr=7.D0                      !RIGHT POINT(psi wont be more than 2*pi)  
     M=2.D0*pi*i/Mlong                         !GENERIC M(0 TO 2PI 100STEPS) 
     call bisecc(f,xl,xr,kmax,tol,k,xm)        !CALLING THE SUBROUTINE
     write(10,*) i,M,theta             ! I WILL PLOT THETA IN FUNCTION OF M
     write(*,*) i,M,theta
   end do 

   close(10)
   write(*,*)
   write(*,*) 'Program ENDED'
   stop
   end program
```

*MY EXTERNAL FUNCTION

---

```
   real*8 function f(psi)
   implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
   real*8 M
   common M,e
    f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M                       !KEPLER EQUATION
   return       
   end function
```