# Do loop only prints last value

Tags: arrays, function, loops, fortran

```
    include 'bisecc.f'  !Incluyo la subrutina del metodo de biseccion
   implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)             !Trabajo en doble precision
   external f     !La funcion vendra definida debajo del end program
   real*8 f     !Tanto ella como la subrutina,en doble precision

   b=0.1D0
   pi=acos(-1.0D0)                           !Declaro el valor de pi

   xl1=b                !El valor que le doy desde la izquierda
   xr1=1.D0                 !El valor que le doy desde la derecha
   xl2=xr1+b
   xr2=2.D0
   xl3=xr2+b
   xr3=3.D0
   xl4=xr3+b
   xr4=3.5D0
   xl5=xr4+b
   xr5=4.D0
   xl6=xr5+b
   xr6=5.D0
   xl7=xr6+b
   xr7=6.D0
   xl8=xr7+b
   xr8=7.D0        
   kmax=100                            !Numero de iteraciones maximo
   tol=0.0001D0                                !Tolerancia del 0.01%
   call bisecc(f,xl1,xr1,kmax,tol,k,xm1)          !Llamo a la subrutina
   call bisecc(f,xl2,xr2,kmax,tol,k,xm2)          !Llamo a la subrutina
   call bisecc(f,xl3,xr3,kmax,tol,k,xm3)          !Llamo a la subrutina
   call bisecc(f,xl4,xr4,kmax,tol,k,xm4)          !Llamo a la subrutina
   call bisecc(f,xl5,xr5,kmax,tol,k,xm5)          !Llamo a la subrutina
   call bisecc(f,xl6,xr6,kmax,tol,k,xm6)          !Llamo a la subrutina
   call bisecc(f,xl7,xr7,kmax,tol,k,xm7)          !Llamo a la subrutina
   call bisecc(f,xl8,xr8,kmax,tol,k,xm8)          !Llamo a la subrutin
   stop
   end program
```

*Function is outside main program,this is the same code as in the other question...

```
real*8 function f(psi)
   implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
   real*8 M(8)
      e=0.2056D0                          
      pi=acos(-1.0D0)                        
      M=(/pi/4.D0,pi/2.D0,3.D0/4.D0*pi,pi,5.D0/4.D0*pi,3.D0*
 &    pi/2.D0,7.D0/4.D0*pi,2.D0*pi/)
      c=sqrt((1.0D0-e)/(1.0D0+e))     
    do i=1,8
     f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(i)                     
    end do 
   return 
   end function
```

Why does my function only use the last value `f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(8)`
 instead of all values of `f` (like this):

`f=psi-e*sin(psi)-M(1:8)`?

Is there a way I can get all values instead of the last result?

Comment: There is no print statement in your do loop. Actually no print statement in your code at all. Your code should not print anything at all!!!! If you have some code that is printing something, show how you are printing it.

Comment: The whole concept of a function is to return **a value** = **one value**. That is the purpose of a function. If you want to print something during the loop, isert a print statement into the loop. If you want to return multiple values to the calling code, use an array. You really have to show us how you are using the function, but first it is **really necessary** explain the difference from your last question.

Comment: yeah i edited the question and changed "print" with "use".My problem is that my program only works for a determined M,like M(1),but not for all M values,M(1:8),i created a do loop so my function uses all M values,but in this loop,the function only uses the last M value,M(8),instead of all.

Comment: If it used all M values,i could get my desired array function and boom problem solved

Comment: Please show the calling code, we really need it. Also, modules will be necessary. Forget implicit typing. Forget it right now.

Comment: What do you mean with calling code and forget implicit typing?coulndt i just get your email and send you both files,so you run it?

Comment: No, I only help here to people on the forum so that others can use it too. You must show the code that uses the function. See also [mcve] If you want to return arrays from functions, you have to use modules and other modern practices and you have to forget obsolete practices like implicit typing.

Comment: Screenshot:http://imgur.com/RyOBnTU

Comment: And this one is a prove that i dont get compilation errors:http://imgur.com/hXM8SVn

Comment: "La compilacion ha terminado con exito" means :"Compilation ended suceesfully"

Comment: You should compile with the flags I showed you before `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`. You are using just `-Wall` and that is not enough. If you don't know how to do that in geany, don't use geany but call *gfortran* in your command line.

Comment: i get this error when i paste that :http://imgur.com/a/yQtl7

Comment: You also have to supply the name of the source file (obviously). And again, you HAVE TO explain why this question is different from the first one. Otherwise one of them will be closed.

Comment: If one of them has to be closed, i wanted to be this one,the other one got edited recently by me to make things clear,

Comment: I just wanted to try something diferent to avoid the other error,so instead of making my function as an array,like in the other question,here i created a do loop to get f as an array,but it only uses the last value not each of them

Comment: It was not a good idea. The `bissect` function needs a very specific type of `f`. You can't change that too easily.

Comment: can you just close this question and read again the previous one?Ive just edited ,i hope you undesrtand what im trying to do when you re-read it